# How can I fixed blur image issue when resize image using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sharp image and it appears clean, but when I resize it using CSS this appears blurry.

How can I fix it?

My code:

[image]

```html
Image with exact pixels:-<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EitPx.jpg" style="margin-left:10px; width:40px; height:27px;" >


<br><br>
Image with modified pixels using css?<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EitPx.jpg" style="margin-left:10px; width:30px; height:20px;" >
```

Comment: It's coming as the same blurry image in both the scenarios for me. The source image is blurry itself.

Comment: You’re not going to get much detail shrinking a 40x27 image down to 30x20, but you could try starting with a PNG file rather than a JPEG. You may prefer the image without the JPEG artifacts, although you won’t see much difference at such a small scale.

Comment: use a good resolution image, that's it

Comment: Convert it to SVG!

Comment: _"I have a sharp image"_ .. no you don't. But that's something already addressed in the comments above

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how it looks like if it's vector (SVG).

```html
Image large:-<br>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg" style="margin-left:10px; width:400px; height:270px;" >


<br><br>
Image with modified pixels using CSS (small) <br>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg" style="margin-left:10px; width:60px; height:40px;" >
```